# How to send a list of data from flutter to android java method channels or eventChannels?

Tags: java, android, flutter, flutter-method-channel, event-channel

```
  void sendData() async {
    final session = StateInheritedWidget.of(context).state.session;
    String Datas;
    try {
      final String result = await sendData.invokeMethod(
          'sendData',{"bVolt":1.5,"hstring":2.5,
            "qString":3.5,"ExternalDeg":5.5,
        "extDeg":6.5,"sessionNo":int.tryParse(session) ?? 0});
      Datas = 'sendData response $result % .';
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      Datas = "Failed to get session response: '${e.message}'.";
    }
  }
```

Here I am passing a string data, I want to pass object data from database and send to android java and retrieve that data from java , How its possible through method channel?

Comment: you are pass it as map right now? are you?

Comment: @eamirho3ein yes can you share a sample code

Comment: sample of what?

Comment: @eamirho3ein
 how to send list of data through method channel

Answer (score 1):

You can Send it as `List of Map` like this:

```
List<Map> data = [
        {
           "bVolt":1.5,
           "hstring":2.5,
           "qString":3.5,
           "ExternalDeg":5.5,
           "extDeg":6.5,
           "sessionNo":int.tryParse(session) ?? 0
        }
];

final String result = await sendData.invokeMethod('sendData',data);
```

and in android part (kotlin) you can try this:

```
val data = (call.arguments) as List;
for (item:Map<String, Any> in data) {
  Log.d("", "item = $item");  
}
```

and in your java part you can make a for loop and access your data:

```
new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL)
        .setMethodCallHandler(
          (call, result) -> {
               if (call.method.equals("sendData")) {
                 var data = (List<Map<String, Object>>)call.arguments;
                 for (Map<String, Object> item : data){
                     Log.d("", "item = $item");  
                 }
               } else {
                 result.notImplemented();
               }
          }
        );
```

Comment: how to retrieve this data from java  code?

Comment: when i added this on my java code getting issues and errors. , I think its kotlin code not working in java.

Comment: i don't know much about koltin and android , can you convert this code to android java.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Unknown class: 'call.arguments' ,  Cannot resolve symbol 'Any' ,  Cannot resolve symbol 'as' , Cannot resolve symbol 'val' , these are the issues .

Comment: Update the question showing the Java code and where you see these errors.

Comment: @eamirho3ein Why do you wrap the map in a list? It's possible to just send the map.

Comment: in the question they ask for pass list, the one way is pass list directly and the other is wrap the list in a map which makes code complex. @RichardHeap

Comment: Yes, but if you read the question, it's not really a list, it's a group/collection/whatever of a bunch of named fields - i.e. a map - `"bVolt":1.5,"hstring":2.5,`

Comment: I assume that they want to pass a list of that map, like:[{"bVolt":1.5, "hstring":2.5,...},{"bVolt":2.5, "hstring":0.5,...},...];

Comment: @eamirho3ein  there issue in update code also in java there is no var dataType ,so I changed it to  List data = (List<Map<String, Object>>)call.arguments; , but there is also issue in  Map<String, Object> item : data  it shows  ''' Required type: Object  Provided: Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>  '''

Comment: sorry I can't help you for the java part, I just no it in kotlin, I hope some body else help you in that.